# Does Qt have anything equivalent to Boost's assign module?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, containers

In Boost there are some convenient functions that let you fill up a container in a single line.

For example, [list_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of) lets you fill a list like so.

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp> // for 'list_of()'
#include <list>
std::list<int> primes = boost::assign::list_of(2)(3)(5)(7)(11);
```

On my project I'm using Qt and cannot use Boost. Is there a similarly convenient way for filling up Qt's containers at the point of construction?

Comment: Why can't you use Boost?

Comment: I think there was a clash with another library we were using. At the end of the day it's part of a large code-base and it's not worth my while to request a new library be introduced to our build process just for this convenience! (Everything else I would rely on is pretty much covered by Qt so far.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use QList::operator<<

```
QList<int> primes = QList<int>() << 2 << 3 << 5 << 7 << 11;
```

Answer (score 6):

From version 4.8 Qt supports the C++11 standard initialization for most containers.

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.8-snapshot/qt4-8-intro.html

Comment: The point of Boost.Assign is to provide an initialization syntax for pre-C++11 compilers.

Comment: @fish And? The question isn't asking about Boost, it's asking whether Qt containers can be filled in similar way. And since 4.8 they can, if you use a C++11 compiler.

Comment: The question is asking if there is an equivalent library for Qt, which would be a library or syntax that does not require a C++11 compiler.

Comment: @fish No, the question is asking whether there _"is a similarly convenient way for filling up Qt's containers at the point of construction"_

Comment: I think it's a reasonable answer - it answers the question and is useful to know. However, I'm going with Kamil's answer as it's more portable for the time being.